Truffle debugger can't connect to node
I'm trying to debug a contract. I have ganache open forking the Ethereum mainnet that uses in the settings the same host and port as my truffle-config.js (127.0.0.1:7545).
I can migrate/deploy and test without issue as these commmands run nicely, but when I try to run truffle debug [txhash] I always get the error message
Starting Truffle Debugger...
CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node http://127.0.0.1:7545.

Any idea what's going wrong here? Thanks
